# new rhythmbox playlists have additional top bar with "artist" & "album."

Tags: rhythmbox

Is there ANY WAY to just GET RID of the "browser views" in Rhythmbox? I can't find any option to do that. It's only happening (to me) with new playlists - older playlists do not have this.